# Relacionar JInternalFrames ingresados por usuario dentro de un JDesktopPane

Tags: java, netbeans

Resulta que estoy realizando un **Modelador** de Base de Datos con tablas (`JInternalFrames` y dentro de esta misma una tabla) que puedan relacionarse entre si, pero no lo he podido realizar.

Para obtener la posición de cada `InternalFrame` estoy tomando los puntos dando clic en la tabla que voy seleccionando.

El código que he realizado es el siguiente:

-"f" es el `JInternalFrame`.

```
    f.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e){
        if(e.getClickCount() == 1){
        super.mouseClicked(e);
        p1 = PanelDeEscritorio.getSelectedFrame().getX();
        p1_1 = PanelDeEscritorio.getSelectedFrame().getY();
        System.out.println(p1);
        System.out.println(p1_1);
        } 
        if(e.getClickCount() == 2){
        super.mouseClicked(e);
        p2 = PanelDeEscritorio.getSelectedFrame().getX();
        p2_2 = PanelDeEscritorio.getSelectedFrame().getY();
        System.out.println(p2);
        System.out.println(p2_2);
        line2d = new Line2D.Double(p1, p1_1, p2, p2_2);
        }
    }
    });
```

Y luego dentro de un botón le agrego el `paintComponent`:

```
   super.paintComponents(g);
   final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
   g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
   g2.setColor(Color.blue);
   g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.5f));
   g2.draw(line2d);
```

No se que me esta faltando ya que no me dibuja la linea, ya he probado de varias maneras y bueno, espero que puedan aportar para ir probando, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que estás intentando dibujar la linea entre las tablas (JInternalFrame) relacionadas, cierto? ¿Porqué con InternalFrame, algún motivo especial?

Comment: Si @RosendoRopher ya que si has utilizado algún modelador de Base de Datos sea StarUML, WorkBench, etc las tablas deberían poder relacionarse, este proyecto es mi tesis de grado, realizar un modelador y gestor de Base de Datos, lo único que nos falta tanto a mis compañeros como a mi es poder relacionar tablas. Lo hice con JInternalFrame porque fue lo primero que se me ocurrió jajaja no tengo muchos conocimientos en Java.

Comment: Vale, solo he usado Oracle Data Modeler y DBVisualizer y en estos no he visto que usen JInternalFrame (ambos son desarrollados en Java) de cualquier forma, tu pregunta existe en el foro en inglés y pienso que esto te puede servir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951383/cubiccurve2d-connecting-two-jinternalframe-instances/3952082#3952082

Comment: Muchas gracias @RosendoRopher :)